# Where should I put `typescript` package for WebStorm to pick it up

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

The [following page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/transpiling-typescript-to-javascript.html) says:

> In the Configure TypeScript Compiler dialog box that opens, choose one
>   of the following options:
>
> - Detect: if you choose this option, WebStorm
>     searches for a typescript package **in the current project**. If a
>     typescript package is found, WebStorm uses it. Otherwise the default
>     bundled package is used. This option is chosen by default.

I have put `typescript` bot into `typescript` and `node_modules/typescript` in the project root. But the IDE doesn't seem to pick it up. It uses bundled 2.0.8 version. Why?

Here my WebStorm version details:

```
WebStorm 2016.3.2
Build #WS-163.9166.30, built on December 12, 2016
Licensed to Maximus Koretskyi
You have perpetual fallback license for this version
Subscription is active until October 16, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_73-b02 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: >I have put typescript bot into typescript and node_modules/typescript in the project root - what did you do exactly? you need installing it in a project using `npm install typescript --save`

Comment: @lena, I simply copied it. When I ran `npm install typescript --save` in the project root, it worked. Do you know why it didn't work when simply copying? And does it need to be in the project root or it can be in a subfolder?

Comment: yes, it has to be in project root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `typescript` package should be located inside `node_modules` folder in the root of the project.